# How to access a control on another window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

After a couple of hours searching to a solution I need some help.

I have a WPF application with a main window and a second window using the RibbonWindow class. The problem is that I am not able to access a control (datagrid) on the MainWindow from a second window. The second window is called (and in the class) CanSubMessages. MainWindow inherits from RibbonWindow and CanSubMessages from Window.

The thing I try to achieve is an updated of the datagrid on MainWindow from the CanSubMessages window. Sounds simple right?

I do the following from CanSubMessages:

```
Window rootWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow as Window;
rootWindow.CanDataGridMessagesCh1.Items.Refresh();
```

And CanDataGridMessagesCh1 is a datagrid in the MainWindow. It's name is given in the corresponding XAML with:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="CanDataGridMessagesCh1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ...
```

I don't see why this control isn't accesible. This is the error I get:

'System.Windows.Window' does not contain a definition for 'CanDataGridMessagesCh1' and no extension method 'CanDataGridMessagesCh1' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Window' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Anybody a clue?

Answer (score 1):

this line is wrong:

```
Window rootWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow as Window;
```

should be

```
Window rootWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow as MyWindowClass;
```

**EDIT**

An alternative solution would be include a reference to your main window in your child window:

Here is an example assuming that you are creating your child window from your main window, and that youve added the main window type into your child window constructor

```
ChildWindow cw = new ChildWindow(this);
```

and then later in your child window:

```
var mainwindow = this.MainWindow; // from the constructor
```

Comment: indeed `MyWindowClass rootWindow = ...`, otherwise it wouldn't compile again.

Comment: Side comment: as a good practice, I would suggest to create a method in your other window, something like: public void UpdateMessageItems(). This will improve isolation between classes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the MyWindowClass seems be be unknown. Is there a special using that I need to use?

Comment: @wlamers: use whatever the real type of your main window has.

Comment: @wlamers: look at my first comment :)

Comment: Well yes did that also ;) I tries to compile but I am keeping the same error. I also tried Jaime his tip, but strangly enough I can not access the method either. Both classes are in the same namespace by the way. Things are getting weird...

Comment: Strangely enough this does not work either. This is the constructor:
    public CanSubMessages(RibbonWindow MainWindow)
        {
            var mainwindow = this.MainWindow;
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

Comment: And this the error message: 
Error 1 'VmsTool.CanSubMessages' does not contain a definition for 'MainWindow' and no extension method 'MainWindow' accepting a first argument of type 'VmsTool.CanSubMessages' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I think it is indeed a good practive to call the method (as Jaime suggests). But even this seems to be not working? Which I think is really weird since it normally would be possible.

Comment: @DeanChalk: using the constructor to pass the handle works well. Activating the parent window using a button for example does work perfectly using mainwindow.Activate(); for example. But strangely enough I do not have access to the public methods inside MainWindow (RibbonWIndow class). Any clue how this is possible? Has it something to do with the RibbonWindow class?